# Transfer function into text file

Tags: matlab, function, transfer

Is there any way to display multiple transfer functions in a text file generated from the script in Matlab? I can't even figure out how to transform them into strings if that is the option to put them into the file.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 1):

I found this somewhere on the web. It seems to give the desired output.

```
transferFunction = tf(1,[1,1,1]);
fid = fopen('test.txt','w');
tfString = evalc('transferFunction');
fprintf(fid,'%s',tfString);
fclose(fid);
```